# SQL campo contiene FieldTerminator

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

Se hace un `BULK INSERT` desde un archivo *CSV* como se ve a continuación:

```
BULK INSERT [bdc_sync_L].[dbo].[Libro_bibliografia]
FROM 'D:\Data Center\Archivos\PRUEBA.csv'
WITH(FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

El problema está en que un registro tiene dentro del título lo siguiente:

```
"Science | Environment | Health"
```

Al momento de ejecutar el `INSERT` marca error porque se desacomodan los datos.
¿Existe una manera de hacer que esos 3 campos se tomen como 1 solo? Y si no, ¿se puede ignorar desde SQL ese registro?

Este es el registro completo que marca error:

> 9789400793798|"Science | Environment | Health"|Towards a Renewed
>   Pedagogy for Science Education|Zeyer, Albert|Springer Netherlands

**No quiero eliminar el registro del CSV ya que son muchos registros, se va a seguir poblando y existe la posibilidad de que se agreguen registros similares**

Comment: Hola ItzyV, bienvenid@ a [es.so], ¿el manejador de base de datos que usas es SQL Server?

Comment: @Flxtr Si, SQL Server

Comment: ¿Existe la forma de manupular el CSV y cambiar el delimitador `|` por algún otro caracter? Con eso sería más sencillo poder hacer la importación de datos sin afectar el contenido las columnas

Comment: No creo que haya solución, se me ocurrió ver si se podían usar quotes para separar cada campo pero el BULK no lo soporta, creo que no queda otra que regenerar el archivo con algún otro separador menos común o "limpiar" los campos.

Comment: Gracias, se cambiara el delimitador entonces